# Como guardar arrays en un objeto nuevo luego de agruparlos

Tags: javascript, array, web

Tengo un array al que le hago un .sort() y muestro solo los primeros diez resultados. Hasta ahí todo bien. Pero ahora necesito que los demas resultados a partir de esos 10 guardarlos en otro array y sumas sus montos, como si fuera uno solo. En este caso hago lo siguiente:

```
.slice(10)
```

Lo que me devuelve:

```
[
{
    "Marca": "ENRIQUE",
    "Rubro": "BIKES",
    "MontoVenta": 321740.53,
    "Cantidad": 12
},
{
    "Marca": "TEKNIAL",
    "Rubro": "BIKES",
    "MontoVenta": 211388.44,
    "Cantidad": 4
},
{
    "Marca": "DAL SANTO",
    "Rubro": "BIKES",
    "MontoVenta": 113075.05,
    "Cantidad": 5
},
{
    "Marca": "VENZO",
    "Rubro": "BIKES",
    "MontoVenta": 38527.69,
    "Cantidad": 2
}]
```

Pero ahora quiero sumar la cantidad de MontoVenta en uno solo y guardarlo en un nuevo arreglo llamado Marca: OTROS para poder acceder al nuevo array y mostrar la cantidad completa de OTROS

Comment: No entendí bien... tienes un array con (por ejemplo) 15 elementos, quieres   que los 10 primeros se vean como son, y los 5 restantes quieres agruparlos en un elemento que sea marca Otros y que monto venta sea la suma de los monto venta de esos 5 elementos? para asi formar un unico array de 11 elementos?

Comment: Exactamente. Pero mantener el monto venta de los 10 elementos como están. Y que el elemento 11 sea la suma de los 5 restantes en uno solo. Y así tenes un array de 11 elementos

Comment: Fran... qué diferencia existe entre esta pregunta y [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/511513/como-agrupar-a-partir-de-primeras-10), que también es tuya y fue cerrada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asi lo puedes hacer (Explicacion como comentarios en el código)

```
let valores = [
{
    "Marca": "ENRIQUE",
    "Rubro": "BIKES",
    "MontoVenta": 321740.53,
    "Cantidad": 12
},
{
    "Marca": "TEKNIAL",
    "Rubro": "BIKES",
    "MontoVenta": 211388.44,
    "Cantidad": 4
},
{
    "Marca": "DAL SANTO",
    "Rubro": "BIKES",
    "MontoVenta": 113075.05,
    "Cantidad": 5
},
{
    "Marca": "VENZO",
    "Rubro": "BIKES",
    "MontoVenta": 38527.69,
    "Cantidad": 2
}];

const FIJOS = 2; //La cantidad de elementos del array que quieres fijos
const restantes = valores.splice(FIJOS); //Sacamos los restantes en un array aparte

const otros = restantes.reduce((acum, e) => {
    //Sumamos los valores de MontoVenta y Cantidad
    acum.MontoVenta+=e.MontoVenta; 
    acum.Cantidad+=e.Cantidad;
    return acum;
}, {
  //Seteamos el valor inicial de Marca y Rubro
  Marca: "Otros", 
  Rubro: "Otros",
  MontoVenta: 0,
  Cantidad: 0
} );

//Una vez calculado el valor de otros, lo agregamos al array original
valores.push(otros);

console.log(valores);
```

Saludos

Comment: Primero: +1 por ser una **excelente** respuesta. Segundo: No le diste la oportunidad a OP de investigar e intentar algo por sí mismo. OP sólo nos planteó el problema, no nos dijo qué había investigado/intentado. Tal vez a la próxima le permitimos construir un poco su conocimiento antes de darles todas las respuestas.